# cron: sending output to file then EMAILing file to me

Tags: email, bash, ubuntu, cron

I am writing a series of cron jobs. I want each task to log its output to file, and then I want the contents of the file mailed to me at say me@somewhere.com

I think logging the output to file can be done using simple pipe redirection like this:

```
30 0 * * * /path/to/script1 > task1.log
30 1 * * * /path/to/script2 > task2.log
```

However, I am not sure how to mail the files (or simply their contents) to me in seperate emails to me@somewhere.com

Also, is there a way to dynamically create the log file names, based on the date, so that the log names would be something like %Y%m%d.task1.log ?

Where the prefix is the date ?

I am running on Ubuntu 10.0.4 LTS

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your system has a working `/usr/bin/sendmail` (doesn't have to be *sendmail* `sendmail`, most mail servers provide a `/usr/bin/sendmail` wrapper script) then you can use the `mail(1)` utility to send mail:

```
echo "hello world" | mail -s hello me@example.com
```

`mail(1)` is pretty primitive; there's no MIME file attachments, you're stuck with plaintext.

If `mutt(1)` is installed, you can use MIME to attach files:

```
echo "hello world" | mutt -a task*.log -- me@example.com
```

As for giving the logfiles dates:

```
$ echo "hi" > $(date "+%Y%m%dlog.txt")
$ cat 20110328log.txt              
hi
$
```

So, try this:

```
30 1 * * * /path/to/script2 > $(date "+\%Y\%m\%dlog.txt") && mutt -a $(date "+\%Y\%m\%dlog.txt") -- me@example.com
```

Comment: The '%' chars need to be escaped before using in a cron script. This caused me all kinds of problems today ;)

Comment: @ommpahloompah, cripes, I'm sorry. :(