# Problems with crontab: I want to log output and email myself the file

Tags: php, cron

I have searched far and wide to no avail.  Perhaps I am simply daft.  I have verified with Dreamhost that they have mutt installed and running on my server, but I do not have access to the error logs from cron.  I am running a php page (this is actually one of many so I really need to figure this out).
I desperately tried to get [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455684/cron-sending-output-to-file-then-emailing-file-to-me) to work.  Nothing.  Nada.  No email.  But it DID create the file.

Here is what I'm running in crontab:

```
MAILTO="me@email.com"
15 13 * * * /usr/local/bin/setlock -n /tmp/cronlock.3783699908.000001 sh -c $'/usr/bin/curl -sS http://mywebsite.com/data_stats.php' > $(date "+/home/jborn/mywebsite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dDATASTATS.txt")  && mutt -a $(date "+/home/jborn/mywebsite.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dDATASTATS.txt") -- me@email.com
```

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/115790/mailto-is-not-working-for-cron-how-can-i-fix-this

Comment: Let me note that it will send me an email if I'm not also trying to capture the output in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what was wrong, but the below is working to load a php page, output the contents to a log file, and email the file.  Note: If I wanted to append the data, I'd use >> instead of >.

15 7 * * * /usr/bin/curl -sS "http://delightful.com/data_stats?no_header=1" > $(date "+/home/jborn/delightful.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dDATAlog.txt") && mutt -s "Data Stats for Today" -a $(date "+/home/jborn/delightful.com/cronlogs/\%Y\%m\%dDATAlog.txt") -- me@email.com