# crontab opening a file and execute a code

Tags: python, cron, export-to-csv

In CRONTAB, is there a way of (i) opening terminal, (ii) opening a file, and then (iii) execute a command ?

What I want to do is each day, open terminal, go to `PycharmProjects/untitled/project1` execute the command `scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv`.

Bonus question: Can crontab email me the result (test.csv)?

Bonus question2: Can crontab upload the result to a server?

Comment: I tried to open the terminal first and then tried to execute a command. But as John Zwinck corrected me, I shouldn't try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but your terminology is a bit off.  We don't "open a terminal" in cron, rather we "run a command."  For example, you could put this in your crontab:

```
00 09 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/project1 && scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv
```

Cron will email you the output of the command by default.  So to receive test.csv via email, if scrapy will just print the output if not given an output file, try this:

```
MAILTO=you@example.com
00 09 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/project1 && scrapy crawl xx
```

If you instead want it as an attachment, see: [cron: sending output to file then EMAILing file to me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455684/cron-sending-output-to-file-then-emailing-file-to-me)

If you instead want to upload it to a server, run whatever that upload command is after another `&&`:

```
00 09 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/project1 && scrapy crawl xx -o test.csv && scp test.csv user@hostname:/some/path
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you very much John Zwinck. It executed the command nicely and emailed me. But I received /bin/sh: scrapy: command not found. Should I add the user name to the path? If so, how do I that? I know it is a basic question but I am really new to coding.

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan: In a regular terminal run `which scrapy` and it will tell you the full path to the program.  Put that full path in the cron job instead of just `scrapy`.

Comment: how do I that? Because when I write 'scrapy crawl xx -o test1.csv' I say crawl the spider xx. should I give the path of that spider? Like this: "00 09 * * * cd PycharmProjects/untitled/project1 && scrapy crawl PycharmProjects/untitled/project1/projectx/spiders/spider1 -o test.csv"

Comment: @AliyarÖzercan: I'm not sure.  Try it.

Comment: I broke it :) now it doesn't send me an email. I tried to change it to back to the line you wrote but still does not work.